# Speed of the color red

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, frequency, dispersion

Taking aside all of the other variables that can alter the color's speed; i.e. sound, mass, water, magnetism. And just focusing on the color itself, how fast does the color red travel, using the means of optical glass?

Comment: The color red is light of a kind-of defined range of wavelengths. So, it propagates at the speed of light in the medium it is in. What 'means of optical glass' means is completely unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

"color" is a construct we use to describe what we experience when interacting with a specified collection of frequencies of light. In other words, color is just a frequency of light. So, "red" moves at the speed of light. It doesn't have a different speed from other colors. Now, if we introduce a medium, this can affect the relative velocities for different frequencies. This is how an index of refraction can be determined in Snell's law.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

All colors or frequencies have the same speed. The speed of an electromagnetic wave only depends on the medium in which the wave travels. What depends on the color or frequency is the refraction angle when an electromagnetic wave change medium, for example from air to crystal or water. The separation of light colors is not a matter of speed but a matter of refraction angle, which can be calculated by Snell law. Hope this helps.

Comment: -1. The refraction angles for different colors are different because they have different refractive indices. The refractive index does affect the speed of light in the medium, and hence different colors only have different refraction angles when they have different speeds in the medium.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I answered too fast, thank you for your correction